# office-js add-in API addAsync hangs the outlook while adding 50+ contacts

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to add email addresses in bcc using Office-JS javascript based add-in (Task Pane). Task Pane UI has list of emails, that I need to add into bcc.
There is an API `Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.addAsync` which takes a list of emails as parameter and add it into bcc.

I am trying to add 500 emails in a bulk of 100 as it supports 100 at a time. This operation is very slow that it freezes/hangs the outlook. I cant do any operations. I can't event click anywhere in the email as it goes into "not responding" mode.

Is this known issue? or is there any workaround to do it?

FYI: Even if I try to add 50 or 10 contacts in a bulk, it freezes/hangs the outlook.

```
function addEmails(contacts=[]){
    const contactsToAdd = contacts.splice(0, contacts.length > 100 ? 100 : contacts.length);
    Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.addAsync(contactsToAdd, function (asyncResult) {
       //on success
       if(contacts.length) {
          addEmails(contacts);
       }
    });
}
```

@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT: Can you please help here. Its a very bad performance issue for me.

Comment: In which Platform are you facing this issue (Windows, OWA, Mac(classic or new UI), Mobile)?

Comment: Windows 10. O365  Version: 16.0.13801.20840

Comment: Is this the known issue?

Comment: Adding bulk recipients simultaneously could result in perf problems. We are looking to improve this behavior.